# WordPress Loop Post Counter Never Changes

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to style the first post differently so I am trying to use a simple counter that will add a class to the first post.

First, on `index.php` I have this

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    $postCount = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        $postCount++;
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
    endwhile;
endif;
```

and then on `content.php` I have

```
<div class="article-wrapper <?php echo $postCount; ?>">
```

but `$postcount` is always 1

If I move `$postCount = 0;` and `$postCount++;` to content.php the value never changes either.

I can create a custom Blog page template but I would like to see this working.

Comment: can you post the hole code? I think you're reset loop everytime it runs, maybe you are using `wp_reset_postdata()` OR `wp_reset_query()` functions.(also checkout the *content.php* file

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am not resetting the loop. I start the counter on index.php and then try to get the value of the counter on content.php but it is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to apply a filter `post_class`. The below code came from this article: https://www.isitwp.com/add-class-to-first-post-in-the-loop/

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wps_first_post_class' );
function wps_first_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $wp_query;
    if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post )
        $classes[] = 'first';
        return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late answer but I think it will help you in other way.
in your `index.php` you can change your code to this

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    $postCount = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        $postCount++;
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type(),['post_counter'=>$postCount] );
    endwhile;
endif;
```

and in your `content.php`

```
if ( $args['post_counter'] ) {
      echo $args['post_counter'];
    }
```